# Tika server ROOT directory

Tags: apache-tika

How can I find the location of the tika server ROOT directory that hosts the html welcome page for the Apache Tika 1.x-SNAPSHOT Server? For example, say that maven built tika in file:///opt/tika-trunk/tika-server/target/classes/org/apache/tika/server/ , so in this path there exist all the classes that maven created. But where is the server root directory and the folder structure that someone would expect, like where is the /detectors folder? where is the /mime-types folder etc.? I am sure missing something important here, so I wish you could give me a hint...

Thanks

Comment: Those paths are not HTML pages... They're JAX-RS endpoints

Comment: @Gagravarr. Oh! maybe that I was missing! Thank you! And where is the root directory that the index.html file of the welcome page for the tika server resides? Do you happen to know also? Thanks again!

Comment: There's no index.html, the welcome page is generated inline in the [TikaWelcome endpoint](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/server/TikaWelcome.java). (There's a plan to move that to using a template file, but no-one has done the work yet)